# Как найти слова через регулярное выражение используя независимый регистр

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Всем привет!
Не могу найти, как мне использовать поиск слов через регулярное выражение вкл нижний регистр, чтобы мне не писать копировать в регулярке kontakty и Kontakty.
Заранее всем благодарен!

```
import re
re.findall(r'(contact|kontakt|контакты|kontakty|feedback)', 'http://www.web.ru/Kontakty/')
```

Answer (score 1):

добавил (?i)

```
import re
result = re.findall('(?i)(contact|kontakt|контакты|feedback)', 'http://www.uralstil.ru/Kontakty/')
```

Answer (score 1):

**Для регистронезависимого поиска с помощью регулярных выражений `re` [используется флаг `re.I` / `re.IGNORECASE`](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/modul-re-dlja-reguljarnyh-vyrazhenij-v-python)** (аналогичный аргумент есть и в библиотеке PyPi `regex`, `regex.I`/`regex.IGNORECASE`):

> **`re.I`** — делает поиск нечувствительным к регистру

Примеры использования в разных функциях `re`:

```py
re.compile(r'\bстрока\b', re.I) # компилирует регистронезависимое регулярное выражение для поиска слов "строка"
re.findall(r'\bстрока\b', text, re.I) # ищет все вхождения целого слова "строка" в тексте независимо от регистра
re.match(r'\bстрока\b', text, re.I)   # ищет вхождение целого слова "строка" в начале текста независимо от регистра 
re.search(r'\bстрока\b', text, re.I)  # ищет вхождение целого слова "строка" где угодно в тексте независимо от регистра 
re.sub(r'\bстрока\b', r'<b>\g<0></b>', text, flags=re.I) # заключает все вхождения целого слова "строка" независимо от регистра в тег <b> (именной аргумент flags тут очень важен!)
```

**Сделать целое выражение регистронезависимым** можно добавив `(?i)` в начале регулярного выражения, т.е. `(?i)<РЕГУЛЯРНОЕ_ВЫРАЖЕНИЕ>`:

> **`(?imx)`** — временно включает параметры `i`, `m` или `x` в регулярное выражение. Если используются круглые скобки — затрагивается только эта область.
> **`(?-imx)`** — временно отключает опции `i`, `m` или `x` в регулярном выражении. Если используются круглые скобки — затрагивается только эта область.

Пример:

```
(?i)(мама|папа)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/t0Oduv/1).

Если нужно **сделать лишь часть выражения регистронезависимым**, используйте группу с модификатором:

> **`(?imx: re)`** — Временно включает параметры `i`, `m` или `x` в круглых скобках.
> **`(?-imx: re)`** — временно отключает опции `i`, `m` или `x` в круглых скобках.

Пример:

```
Пропала\s+(?i:собака|кошка)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/t0Oduv/2) (к сожалению, при тестировании на regex101 этот конструкт не работает, поэтому я выбрал опцию .NET, [в коде всё работает](https://ideone.com/Iaa4Aw)).